# In R, reading .txt file with no spaces between the words?

Tags: r

In R, I want to read a .txt file that contains characters only however, there are no spaces in between.how can i differentiate in R based on English dictionary? example "oneshoulddothatheshouldalwayslearn" output should be "one should do that he should always learn" thanks

Comment: read.txt file can not specify the english dictionary word . you can separate them by comma , semicolon or any string sign.

Comment: You sure it's "do that" and not "dot hat"?

Comment: That you have such a file means something went wrong when it was created. Focus on fixing that process and create the file again.

Comment: You need a dictionary of valid words and an algorithm that looks for words and does a bit of backtracking if it gets stuck. Have you tried?

Comment: Thanks a lot, everyone. It had been asked by one of the recruiters in the interview. The question was " if there is a text file and the words don't have any spaces between them so is it possible to separate them- assume they all are English dictionary words with no special characters?"

Answer (score 6):

Here's a function that does it:

```
unmash <- function(original, sofar=c(), rest=original, words){
    for(L in 1:nchar(rest)){
        finding = substr(rest,1,L)
        m = grep(paste0("^",finding,"$"), words)
        if(length(m)>0){
            rest2 = substr(rest,L+1,nchar(rest))
            if(rest2==""){
                message("Original: ",original," = ",paste(c(sofar,finding),collapse=","))
            }else{
                unmash(original, c(sofar,finding), rest2, words)
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

You need a wordlist. I get mine with this:

```
words = function(f){
    w = scan(f,what="")
    w = w[nchar(w)>1]
    w = c(w,"a","i","o")
    w
}
wordlist= words("/usr/share/dict/words")
```

where that file is a standard Unix file of one word per line. However it contains almost every single letter as a word, so the function above removes most of them except a,i, and o.

Here's my function run on your example - note there are five possible splits into valid words that are in my dictionary:

```
> test = "oneshoulddothatheshouldalwayslearn"
> unmash(test, words=wordlist)
Original: oneshoulddothatheshouldalwayslearn = one,should,do,that,he,should,always,learn
Original: oneshoulddothatheshouldalwayslearn = one,should,dot,ha,the,should,always,learn
Original: oneshoulddothatheshouldalwayslearn = one,should,dot,hat,he,should,always,learn
Original: oneshoulddothatheshouldalwayslearn = one,should,doth,a,the,should,always,learn
Original: oneshoulddothatheshouldalwayslearn = one,should,doth,at,he,should,always,learn
>
```